# Evaluating $(\sqrt{3}+i)^{2017} + (\sqrt{3} - i)^{2017}$

Tags: calculus

I'm having a problem with following equation:

I'm applying $(a+b)^2$ and $(a-b)^2$, but am unable to get the correct answer.

> $$(\sqrt{3}+i)^{2017} + (\sqrt{3} - i)^{2017}$$

Comment: What have you gotten?  (Please include the work you've done, even if you found it doesn't yield the correct answer.)  Alternatively, you may cite the source of the question, and explain why it is of interest to you and or the general community.

Comment: Yeah my bad, it's my first post :).
What i tried was to apply the basic rules of $(a+b)^2$ and $(a-b)^2$. So what i got is

$$(\sqrt{3}+i)^{2017} + (\sqrt{3} - i)^{2017} = 3^{1008}\sqrt{3} + 3^{1008}\sqrt{3}$$

I'm not sure it's the correct way to approach with complex numbers. I used $(a+b)^3$, but that didn't seem right also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Euler's formula. Say $z = \sqrt{3} + i$.
So $tan(\phi) = 1/\sqrt{3}$
and $\phi = \pi/6$
and $r = |z|= \sqrt{1^2 + \sqrt{3}^2} = \sqrt{4} = 2$
Meaning $z = 2 \cdot e^{i \pi/6}$, $\overline z = 2 \cdot e^{-i \pi/6}$

$z^{2017} = 2^2017 \cdot e^{i \cdot 2017 \cdot\pi/6}$, $(\overline z)^{2017} = 2^{2017} \cdot e^{-i \cdot 2017 \cdot\pi/6}$

Converting this back from $w= |w| \cdot e^{i \cdot \psi}$ to the form $w = a + ib$ 
with $Re(w) = a = |w|cos(\psi)$ and $Im(w) = b = |w|sin(\psi)$

gives us 
$$z^{2017} + (\overline z)^{2017} = \\\
Re(z^{2017}) + Re((\overline z)^{2017}) + i\cdot (Im(z^{2017}) + Im((\overline z)^{2017})) = \\\
2^{2017} cos(2017 \cdot \pi / 6) + 2^{2017} cos(- 2017 \cdot \pi /6) + i\cdot (2^{2017} sin(2017 \cdot \pi / 6) + 2^{2017} sin(- 2017 \cdot \pi / 6)) = \\\
2^{2017} cos(2017 \cdot \pi / 6) + 2^{2017} cos(2017 \cdot \pi /6) + i\cdot (2^{2017} sin(2017 \cdot \pi / 6) - 2^{2017} sin(2017 \cdot \pi / 6)) = \\\
2^{2017} (2 \cdot cos(2017 \cdot \pi /6)) = \\\
2^{2017} (2 \cdot cos(\pi /6)) = \\\
2^{2017} (2 \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) = \\\
2^{2017} \sqrt{3}  
$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

It's probably easier to write $\sqrt 3+i=re^{i\theta}$ and $\sqrt 3-i=re^{-i\theta}$, by finding $r,\theta$, and then use $$r\cos(\theta)=r\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=(\sqrt 3 +i)^{2017}$, then $$z=2^{2017}e^{2017 i\pi /6}$$

$$Re(z)=2^{2017}\cos {2017\pi /6} =2^{2017} \cos {\pi/6}$$

$z+\bar z =2Re(z)=2^{2017}\sqrt 3$

Comment: The exponent was supposed to be 2017 rather than 2007. In your case that means you get $Re(z) = 2^{2017} cos(2017 \pi/6)$ which is $2^{2017} cos(\pi /6) = 2^{2017} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I fixed my mistake